# pandas group by and convert rows into multiple columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pivot-table, pandas-groupby

```
data = {'groupId':[1,1,2], 'email':['a1@gmail.com', 'a2@gmail.com', 'a3@gmail.com'],
        'type':['office','personal','personal'],'name':['santy','santy','will']} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I have a dataframe like this

```
groupId email   type           name
1   a1@gmail.com    office      santy
1   a2@gmail.com    personal    santy
2   a3@gmail.com    personal    will
```

I want to transform rows into dynamic columns depending on the number of rows in in particular group

```
groupId email1         type1   email2          type2       name
1      a1@gmail.com  office    a2@gmail.com    personal    santy
2      a3@gmail.com   personal   na              na        will
```

I know I can use set_index with unstack but confused on how I can give the column names and create those many columns as in particular group.

Is there efficient way do do this?
Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
new_df = (df.assign(col=df.groupby('groupId').cumcount()+1)
   .set_index(['groupId','col'])
   .unstack('col')
   .sort_index(level=(1,0), axis=1)
)

new_df.columns = [f'{x}{y}' for x,y in new_df.columns]
```

Output:

```
               email1     type1        email2     type2
groupId                                                
1        a1@gmail.com    office  a2@gmail.com  personal
2        a3@gmail.com  personal           NaN       NaN
```

Comment: what if there is one more field which I dont want to convert to column

Comment: add it to `set_index`: `set_index(['groupId','name','col'])`.

Comment: I just modified the question.